# Azure Cosmos DB in local DOcker container SSL connection error

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am running a local Cosmos DB in Docker container. I have followed this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-develop-emulator?tabs=docker-linux%2Ccsharp&pivots=api-nosql#export-the-emulators-tlsssl-certificate).

I am running Azure Function in Visual Studio Code. I have also imported the SSL certificate of Cosmos DB from Docker using this [method](https://www.sonicwall.com/support/knowledge-base/how-can-i-import-certificates-into-the-ms-windows-local-machine-certificate-store/170504615105398/). I am running on Windows 11 OS.

However I keep getting this error:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.MyCoFunc'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB: Cannot create container information for products in database cosmicworks4 with lease leases in database cosmicworks4 : The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. System.Net.Http: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. System.Private.CoreLib: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot.
[2023-12-23T16:54:16.993Z] Error indexing method 'Functions.MyCoFunc'
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Function_CosmosDB_Trigger
{
    public class MyCoFunc
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public MyCoFunc(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MyCoFunc>();
        }

        [Function("MyCoFunc")]
        public void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "cosmicworks4",
            containerName: "products",
            Connection = "DBConnectionString",
            LeaseContainerName = "leases",
            CreateLeaseContainerIfNotExists = true)] IReadOnlyList<MyDocument> input)
        {
            if (input != null && input.Count > 0)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Documents modified: " + input.Count);
                _logger.LogInformation("First document Id: " + input[0].id);
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyDocument
    {
        public string id { get; set; }

        public string Text { get; set; }

        public int Number { get; set; }

        public bool Boolean { get; set; }
    }
}
```

what is wrong?

tks

Comment: Have you correctly imported the SSL certificate of Cosmos DB into the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store on the machine where your Azure Functions runtime is running.

Comment: @MohamedAzarudeenZ I do have imported the SSL also in the Trusted Root Certification but I still get the same error.

Comment: @toto' post importing the certificate by selecting Trusted Root, are you able to see [this](https://i.imgur.com/vfIi1ZQ.png) message?

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin yes the certificate shows that status.

Comment: @toto' can you try to use local cosmos db emulator in visual studio directly? You can configure it while creating the function itself

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin what do you mean locally in visual studio directly?? I have installed the emulator directly on Windows ( i.e. not in Docker!) and in such way it works. The problem seems to be only when the emulator runs in Docker.

Answer (score 1):

Even Initially I got the same error.

[image]

I did the following steps to resolve this error-

- Exported the certificate

[image]

- Installed the certificate by adding it to **Trusted Root Certificate Authorities** certificate store.

[image]

[image]

- After doing the above steps, When I debugged my function, I got the expected response.

[image]

- Even you can make use of it in Visual Studio as shown below-

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks. I do have followed the import process of the cert from the browser (first exporting it and then importaing it) and looks better. However in my case the browser still shows the warning "Not Secure". I do not understand why in your case the browser is not complaining with certitifcate.

Comment: @toto' can you try using edge?

Comment: With Edge I get the same Warning.

Comment: @toto' try clearing cache and invoke the url. Its a browser issue, as the certificate is already been added to trusted root

Comment: Yep, I tried in incognito and it works. thanks!