# Cosmos DB Emulator Container - can't export certificate

Tags: azure, docker, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to run the Cosmos DB Emulator Windows Container image, using the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-develop-emulator?tabs=docker-windows%2Ccsharp&pivots=api-nosql

I'm at the point where the container is running and I can see the data explorer.  So this is good!  I'm now attempting to export the emulator's certificate so that I can import locally and run, using these instructions (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-develop-emulator?tabs=docker-windows%2Ccsharp&pivots=api-nosql#export-the-emulators-tlsssl-certificate):

curl -k https://localhost:8081/_explorer/emulator.pem > ~/emulatorcert.crt

However, this results in a 'Not Found'.  I've tried that URL in a browser, and I get a 404.

1. Am I doing something wrong?  I'd like to be able to use this container w/o having to install the emulator locally.
2. Is there another way to get this certificate from the container, so that I can connect without warnings?  I will also be connecting to this via a .NET application, so I was hoping to not have to jump through hoops to disable TLS verification.

Thanks.

Comment: Check this SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77708392/azure-cosmos-db-in-local-docker-container-ssl-connection-error/77721613#77721613 to import the certificate manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there another way to get this certificate from the container, so that I can connect without warnings? I will also be connecting to this via a .NET application, so I was hoping to not have to jump through hoops to disable TLS verification.

In order to export the SSL certificate you can follow the below approach-

1. Click on Not Secure --> Certificate is not valid

[image]

2. Go to **Details** tab as shown below and then click on Export to export the certificate to your local machine.

[image]

3. Once the Certificate is exported, you will be able to see below message when you will open it. Click on **Install Certificate** to import it.

[image]

4. Follow the below steps to add the certificate to the **Trusted Root Certification Authorities** while importing it to your local machine.

[image]

[image]

Click Next and then Finish the installation process. Once you have successfully imported, you will be see below message when you will open the certificate.

[image]

Browse `https://localhost:8081/_explorer/index.html` URL in Incognito mode or by clearing the cache of the same browser, you will no longer see **Not secure** warning.

[image]